# How to remove the last empty line in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to remove the last empty line in vim? I mean the line at the bottom of the window, below the line in which I type the command with the colon symbol (see the image [Line2Remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ji7t.png)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the following command, and check what it returns:

```
:set cmdheight
```

If it's greater than 1, set it to 1:

```
:set cmdheight=1
```